# How to add custom template in a datepicker.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Im using bootstrap datepicker http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for my project and I would like to know how can I add the custom icon for a particular day. My requirements is adding icons for events on a particular date.

[image]

the image shows the output (icon on 15th day) which i required. Looking forward for a solutions. Thanks in advance. :)

code which i used.

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        forceParse: false,
        templates:{
            leftArrow: '<i class="material-icons icon-30">keyboard_arrow_left</i>',
            rightArrow: '<i class="material-icons icon-30">keyboard_arrow_right</i>',
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var d = date;
            var curr_date = d.getDate();
            var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
            var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
            var formate_date = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year
            if ($.inArray(formate_date, specific_date) != -1){
                return {
                    classes: 'addIcon' // Here i want to add an icon for a partiicular date.
                };
            }
        }

    });
```

[image: This is what I actually want. :)]

Answer (score 1):

You can use add class in your specific day using **beforeShowDay** event

```
var specific_date = ["15/12/2017","16/12/2017"];
beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var d = date;
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var formate_date = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year
    if ($.inArray(formate_date, specific_date) != -1){
        return {
            classes: 'addIcon'
        };
    }
    return;
}
```

> then you can add anything using css

```
.addIcon::after{
    content: "\25CF";
    font-size:10px;
    color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 12px;
  }
  .day{
    position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @bipin. but what i need is to add an icon to a particular date. :). I have used the template options for changing the left and right arrow. Similarly is there any options for adding a template to a particular date.?

 if ($.inArray(formate_date, specific_date) != -1){
        return {
            template: ' <i class="material-icons icon-30">keyboard_arrow_left</i>'
        };
    }

Comment: You can use CSS for design icon

Comment: please find the image which I required. :)

Comment: Right now not possible to add HTML you can design your icon using CSS i have update my CSS for you hint

Comment: Thanks bipin. :) i somehow managed using jquery 
$('.datepicker').on('click', function () {
                $(".table-condensed:first td.addIcon").append('<i class="material-icons icon-30 icon-event icon-blue">lens</i>')
            });
but while click on the next and prev icon it doesnt show the icon.
But i have a fix now. I will convert all the icons into fonts then i can use that particular icon.
Once again thank u very much . :)

Comment: This really helps me to achieve my requirments thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Okay welcome but you can also check on change month i think at that time some issue you face for added HTML